# How to declare a function with a concrete return type conforming to a protocol?

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, generics

EDIT:
This question was written before `swift` added the `some` keyword, making it obsolete

In objective-c I could declare a method with a return type:

```
-(UIView<MyProtocol> *)someMethod;
```

In this example the method returns a `UIView` that conforms to a protocol `MyProtocol`.

I want to do something like that in swift:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
  var someProperty : Int {get set}
}

protocol MyDelegate {
  func someMethod() -> UIView : MyProtocol // the view should conform to the protocol - I don't care what kind of view it is - I don't want to define a specific type of view
}
```

In general - The delegate should return a `UIView` with the var "`someProperty`"

I **don't** want to define a concrete `UIView` class.
I want the user to be able to return **any** type of `UIView` (As long as it conforms to the protocol)

The syntax I wrote is invalid - How should I be writing it?

Comment: Likely you can do such things in many programming language. There is no specific relationship to Objective-C. Removed the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was written before the days of swift-ui

The "some" keyword has solved it by allowing opaque types to be returned from functions

```
protocol MyDelegate {
  func someMethod() -> some MyProtocol 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the protocol as type:

```
protocol MyDelegate {
    func someMethod() -> MyProtocol
}
```

And use it like this:

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    var someProperty : Int {get set}
}

class CustomView: UIView, MyProtocol {
    var someProperty = 2
}

protocol MyDelegate {
    func someMethod() -> MyProtocol
}

struct Delegate: MyDelegate {
    func someMethod() -> MyProtocol {
        return CustomView()
    }
}

let delegate = Delegate()
let view = delegate.someMethod()
let property = view.someProperty // property = 2
```

Comment: The first doesnt answer the question for sure. Ill try the second

Comment: Fair enough it's missing the `UIView` constraint, but it can guarantee protocol conformance.

Comment: Not working ; getting an error : Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'

Comment: I had some Xcode hiccup, so it didn't throw an error, but I see that I was wrong. Updated my answer with the only working example (I'm not sure how you could do it).

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Swift. Not everything possible in Obj-C has to be possible in Swift. When creating a type requirement you can only combine protocols using the `protocol<..., ...>` syntax but you can't combine a class and a protocol.

Technically, this should be good for your architecture. You can probably find a workaround but I would advice against it. There is a reason to avoid combining classes with protocols because the interfaces are much more difficult to handle. Most OOP languages don't have that syntax. Many commonly used languages don't even have a syntax to combine protocols.

Comment: Of course they do. Almost all languages can inherit from one superclass and implement as many interfaces (protocols) as they want.

Comment: It is a well used pattern in all of objective-c and UIKit/Foundation frameworks.

Comment: @AvnerBarr I am not speaking about inheritance, I am speaking about specifying a type requirement when passing parameters, returning from methods etc. I know it's possible in Obj-C (not used so often but possible). It's impossible in most other languages, including Swift.

Comment: Uikit defines methods of return type Uiview which implement interfaces. This is very useful for adding views to heirarchy without imposing specific type, yet having defined methods and variables on the object

Comment: @AvnerBarr Could you maybe link one of them? I can't remember any such method at the moment. Anyway, I know it can be useful but there are cleaner ways to do the same. Swift just doesn't have this feature, the same as most other languages.

Answer (score 0):

```
protocol MyProtocol {
  var someProperty : Int {get set}
}

protocol MyDelegate {
  func someMethod<T: UIView & MyProtocol>() -> T // the view should conform to the protocol - I don't care what kind of view it is - I don't want to define a specific type of view
}

class MyDelegateTestView : UIView, MyProtocol {
    var someProperty: Int = 10
}

class MyDelegateTestClass : MyDelegate {
    func someMethod<T>() -> T where T : UIView, T : MyProtocol {
        return MyDelegateTestView() as! T
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Here below is a way.

```
func myMethod(string: String) -> MyClass:MyProtocol? {

}
```

You can use without optional type as MyClass: MyProtocol.

Comment: Getting the same error : Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'